# How to add user to a MailChimp group?

Tags: mailchimp

I'm using MailChimp API for adding subscriber to list. I have created three type of group. I wanted to add the user to particular group. How can I do that?
Here is my code:

```
    $MailChimp = new \Drewm\MailChimp(MAILCHIMP_KEY);

    $result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
        'id'=> MAILCHIMP_LIST,
        'email' => array('email'=>$data['email']),
        'merge_vars' => array('FNAME'=>$data['first_name'],
            'LNAME'=>$data['last_name'],
            'TITLE'=>$data['title'],
            'COMPANY'=>$data['company'],
            'PROFESSION'=>$profession,
            'ADDRESS'=>'',
            'groupings' => array(array('id' => 'id1234')),
        ),
        'double_optin'      => false,
        'update_existing'   => true,
        'replace_interests' => false,
        'send_welcome'      => false,
    ));
```

Comment: If you're using V3 API then this is the answer you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/47159262/8733158

Answer (score 0):

Reference the [API Docs](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php) for details. Adding to groups requires a `groupings` item to your `merge_vars` array, which you have. That should be an array (good so far). The array should contain associative arrays (still good). Each of those should have an `id` containing the ID of the grouping and a `groups` array with the names of the groups you want to add the user to. Like so:

```
{
  "merge_fields": {
    "groupings": [
      {"id": "some_grouping_id", "groups": ["group1", "group2"]}
    ]
  }
}
```

In v3, this is a good bit easier. There's an `interests` object that just takes IDs and Booleans to determine if a user is added to or removed from a group.